# How to align elements inside a stack in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have an image slider. On top of the image slider three dots should be displayed the change the image. The dots should be centered at the bottom of the image. Additionaly I need a button also as an overlay. The button should be displayed on the right side vertically centered.
I use a stack but I'm not able to align the control elements.

```
Stack(children: [
        CarouselSlider(
          items: children,
          options: CarouselOptions(
              autoPlay: false,
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              aspectRatio: 2.0,
              enableInfiniteScroll: false,
              onPageChanged: (newIndex, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  currentImage = newIndex;
                });
              }),
        ),
        // This row should be at the bottom of the image slider
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: children.map((url) {
            index++;
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: currentImage == index - 1
                    ? Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.9)
                    : Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.4),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
        // This row should be centered on the right
        Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight,child: PhotoButtons(eventId: widget.event.id, preview: true))
      ]),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can align the children widgets in a `Stack` by using the `alignment` property.

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children: [
    // Your widgets
  ],
),
```

This will align all the children at the bottom center, but we don't want that, right?

So, we will use another widget know as `Positioned` widget. We can specify the exact position of our widget from the `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom`. By using `MediaQuery`, you can easily display it in the center-right position.

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children: [
    // Your widgets
    Positioned(
      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
      right: 0, // the position from the right           
    ),
  ],
),
```

Please note that `Positioned` widget can be used only in a `Stack` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Use Positioned widget instead of Align, [take a look this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgtPleVwxBQ&feature=emb_logo)

Answer (score 0):

Add the align widget in the stack and then change its alignment to wherever you want the widget to show in that stack space

```
Stack(
 children: [    
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment:
    MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
    for (var i = 0;i < localImages.length;i++)
      Text('.',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60,color:Colors.grey),)
    ],
  ))
 ])
```

Comment: That will create the dots for at the bottom Center for the number of images you have